# Need a special query to insert data using cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a table structure like below :

```
======================================
  id | year | Quater |  amount |Status
======================================
  1  | 2011 | 1      |  2500   | 0
======================================
  2  | 2011 | 2      |  2500   | 0
```

This is one kind of payment table.In this table, if you see total amount is 5000.If i want to pay 3000 thousand, than 2500 will be deduct from for quater 1 and status will be update to 0 or 1.And remaining 500 should subtract from 2500-500 = 2000 and it will the inserted in third rows in the given table with status 1 and second row's status will be updated from 0 to 2.

How can I do this things.If there is a problem to understan,than please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: What you seem to have is a logic problem. If you want to ask a question about cake it should be of the form "how can I do _this_ in CakePHP?" right now your question is "What should I do?" which is too broad and off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with AD7six. You can add one more filed 'user.id', when you recive payment you can find user's row and sum them

```
$sum = $this->Payment->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
                                                'user_id' => $uId ),
                                            'fields' => array('sum(Paymnet.amount) AS money')));
```

then you can minus current amount  out of $sum and save them in db. I hope you know how to modify `$this->request->data`